# AngularJS routing with templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I have a problem with the AngularJS routing: I don't get any feedback of the page. No errors or view-switches.

I checked my implementation of the module, but it's declared in the right way. Then I searched for typos such as `templateURL`, but I didn't find any. I also tried to use `ng-href` instead of `href` in the list, but then the links weren't clickable anymore.

[Here is my **plunker**.](http://plnkr.co/edit/dX25tGBGG75Jv2Ow9mAD)

And my code:

1. Created my navigation:

   ```
   <body ng-app="Productportfolio">

   <ul>
     <li>
       <a href="#/home">Home</a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href='#/privat'>Log in</a>
    </li>
   </ul>

   <ng-view></ng-view>

   <!--own js -->
   <script src="app.js"></script>
   <!--Controller -->
   <script src="ProductCtrl.js"></script>
   <!--Services -->
   <!--Direktives-->
   </body>
   ```

2. Made the templates:

   ```
   //home.html
   <div>
     <h1> Home </h1>
   </div>

   //private.html
   <div>
     <h1> Private</h1>
   </div>
   ```
3. Declared a Angular module:

   ```
   angular.module('Productportfolio', ['ngRoute'])
   ```
4. Added the $routeProvider to my config:

   ```
   angular.module('Productportfolio', ['ngRoute', 'ProductService', 'ProductCtrl'])

   .config(['$routeProvider, $locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

     $routeProvider

       .when('/home', {
           templateUrl: 'home.html',
           controller: 'ProductCtrl'
       })

       .when('/private', {
           templateUrl: 'private.html',
           controller: 'ProductCtrl'
       })

       .otherwise({
           redirectTo: '/home',
           controller: 'ProductCtrl'
       });

     $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

   }]);
   ```

Comment: Which is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: I don't get any error; I get no feedback of the page

Comment: jQuery has to be loaded before angular gets loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Plunker, there were some issues related to imports. To make it easy, I simply removed both **jQuery** and **Bootstrap**. I also put all your modules in a single **app.js** file.

There were some errors in your **html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>

    <!--AngularJS-->
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="Productportfolio">

  <ul>
    <li>
      <a ng-href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a ng-href="#private">Private</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

    <ng-view></ng-view>

    <!--own js -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

- Import `Angular` BEFORE `ngRoute` or any other module
- Use `ng-href='#routeName'` or, otherwise

And in your **js**:

```
var myApp = angular.module('Productportfolio', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.controller('ProductCtrl', ['$scope',function ($scope) {
  var vm = this;
}]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider
            .when('/home', {
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
                controller: 'ProductCtrl'
            })

            .when('/private', {
                templateUrl: 'private.html',
                controller: 'ProductCtrl'
            })

            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/home',
                controller: 'ProductCtrl'
            });
}]);
```

- You need to inject only external modules in your app module, not all controller, services etc

Notice that, to make it easy, I removed also your Service since you did not share it and it was useful.

Last but not least, if you want to use `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');` to use `hashbangs`, you need to add `<base href="/" />` at the end of your `head`.

For some reason, plunker does not allow me to do that, but I'm sure you'll get it to work on your version.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/GueJKvmP8VgLd8ibJyRg?p=info) You can find the working plunker reproducing your application.

Hope I've been helpful.

Comment: I think we wrote the comment in the same minute, so I didn't saw it before. You explained it ways better than me. And the part with the $locationProvider ist good to know :)

Comment: relevant comment for missing base tag declaration in header tag.

Answer (score 3):

The remaining and not visible problem is here :

```
angular.module('Productportfolio', ['ngRoute', 'ProductService', 'ProductCtrl'])
.config(['$routeProvider, $locationProvider',
```

`config()` function of module object takes as parameter, a array of strings and not a string with "," as separator char inside it.
See example and doc here :
 [https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#provider-recipe](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module)

So, it should be :

```
angular.module('Productportfolio', ['ngRoute', 'ProductService', 'ProductCtrl'])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
```

---

**Update** :

But in fact, in your case, it works even without precising the array :

```
angular.module('Productportfolio', ['ngRoute', 'ProductService', 'ProductCtrl'])
.config(
```

---

I updated the plunker and the app.js with both versions. I have the impression that the array is not mandatory (any longer). So, it seems better to ignore that parameter, especially, if with bad value, it may create side-effects.

Here the plunker with corrections (ordered lib, typos and config function called) :
http://plnkr.co/edit/NTn6Zmav5RX4V8zgHPOG?p=preview

I have removed `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!')` as not suitable for the url you are using. See @AndreaM16 answer for that.

Besides, you have not declared your service you want to use in your controller.

app.js

```
angular.module('Productportfolio', ['ngRoute'])
       .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
            function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $routeProvider
            .when('/home', {
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
                controller: 'ProductCtrl'
            })

            .when('/private', {
                templateUrl: 'private.html',
                controller: 'ProductCtrl'
            })

            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/home',
                controller: 'ProductCtrl'
            });


        }]
    );
```

or app.js without the array parameter in `config` function :

```
angular.module('Productportfolio', ['ngRoute'])
       .config(
            function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $routeProvider
            .when('/home', {
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
                controller: 'ProductCtrl'
            })

            .when('/private', {
                templateUrl: 'private.html',
                controller: 'ProductCtrl'
            })

            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/home',
                controller: 'ProductCtrl'
            });

       // $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
        }
    );
```

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <!--Bootstrap-->
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="https://www.atlasestateagents.co.uk/javascript/tether.min.js"></script><!-- Tether for Bootstrap --> 
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.2" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.2" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


    <!--AngularJS-->
        <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script>


    <!--own js -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <!--Controller -->
    <script src="ProductCtrl.js"></script>
    <!--Services -->
    <!--Direktives-->
  </head>

  <body ng-app="Productportfolio">

  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#private">Log in</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div ng-view></div>


  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any idea on why Plunker does not really like `hashPrefix`? Never seen that.

Comment: @AndreaM16, No idea. Maybe a side effect with base url. You have already used hashPrefix with Plunker ?

Comment: Well no, never used it, but I usually use it in my applications.

Comment: Ah ok. In my applications I use it too and no problem too.

Answer (score 1):

**The order of loading java script files is very important**. Load in the following order:

```
<link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.2" rel="stylesheet" 
              href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.0.0" 
              src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.atlasestateagents.co.uk/javascript/tether.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.2" 
          src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


<!--AngularJS-->
<script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" 
            src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.5.8" 
           src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script>
```

It means that you are loading `Bootstrap.js` files, but Bootstrap cannot work without `jQuery` library. So it means you should load `jQuery` at first, then `Bootstrap.js`. And other libraries should be reordered(I've shown in an example above).

In addition, you can use `Console` in your browser to see whether there are errors and what errors you have.

Comment: thank you, I think, that I also have to change the order of      angular and      angular-routes. But it does not solve the problem