# angularjs ng-route. not work templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, nw.js, angularjs-ng-route

It does not work with the specified templateUrl: test.html but works if you specify the template: 'Hello '

WORK

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/test', {
        template: '<h1>home</h1>',
        controller: 'ctrl'
    })

    // .otherwise({
    //  redirectTo: '/home',
    //  controller: 'ProductCtrl'
    // });
});
```

DO NOT WORK

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/test', {
        templateUrl: 'test.html',
        controller: 'ctrl'
    })

    // .otherwise({
    //  redirectTo: '/home',
    //  controller: 'ProductCtrl'
    // });
});
```

and  I have a sign `!` in the path to the file that is `#!/test`

LINK

```
<a style="color:white;" href="#!/test">Go</a>
```

I'm using nw.js

Comment: show your folder structure where you put your test.html file

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635098/angularjs-routing-with-templateurl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to put a path to your template url

```
.when('/test', {
   templateUrl: './test.html',
   controller: 'ctrl'
  })
```